# How to do multiple Kafka topics to multiple Spark jobs in parallel

Tags: apache-spark, flink-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

Please forgive if this question doesn't make sense, as I am just starting out with Spark and trying to understand it.

From what I've read, Spark is a good use case for doing real time analytics on streaming data, which can then be pushed to a downstream sink such as hdfs/hive/hbase etc.

I have 2 questions about that. I am not clear if there is only 1 spark streaming job running or multiple at any given time. Say I have different analytics I need to perform for each topic from Kafka or each source that is streaming into Kafka, and then push the results of those downstream.

Does Spark allow you to run multiple streaming jobs in parallel so you can keep aggregate analytics separate for each stream, or in this case each Kafka topic. If so, how is that done, any documentation you could point me to ?

Just to be clear, my use case is to stream from different sources, and each source could have potentially different analytics I need to perform as well as different data structure. I want to be able to have multiple Kafka topics and partitions. I understand each Kafka partition maps to a Spark partition, and it can be parallelized.

I am not sure how you run multiple Spark streaming jobs in parallel though, to be able to read from multiple Kafka topics, and tabulate separate analytics on those topics/streams.

If not Spark is this something thats possible to do in Flink ?

Second, how does one get started with Spark, it seems there is a company and or distro to choose for each component, Confluent-Kafka, Databricks-Spark, Hadoop-HW/CDH/MAPR. Does one really need all of these, or what is the minimal and easiest way to get going with a big data pipleine while limiting the number of vendors ? It seems like such a huge task to even start on a POC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked multiple questions so I'll address each one separately.

1. Does Spark allow you to run multiple streaming jobs in parallel?

Yes

2. Is there any documentation on Spark Streaming with Kafka?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

3. How does one get started?

a. Book: [https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Spark-Lightning-Fast-Data-Analysis/dp/1449358624/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358624)

b. Easy way to run/learn Spark: https://community.cloud.databricks.com

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am still not clear on how you read multiple isolated topics from Kafka in Spark, and maintain aggregate level data on those isolated streams. The documentation you provided I have gone through, but only shows how to configure Spark for reading from a single topic. I want to have multiple jobs and read a separate topic in each job, and maintain numbers on each stream separately. Any thoughts ? Maybe I can reword my initial question if that will help.  Thanks..

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly then you want two separate Spark apps with each app reading from a separate Kafka stream. Is this accurate? If so, then the solution is to write two separate Spark applications.

Comment: Yes that is exactly it, so its possible to have 2 completely separate Spark applications which do not share any data if we do not want them to ? That is exactly what I want. I cannot find an example of how to do that. BTW, is it possible to share data between the 2 separate jobs if one wanted to ?

Comment: Yes, you can have two totally separate Spark applications running on the cluster. You can have as many applications as your hardware will support.

Yes, you can share data between applications. Typically, you'd write to disk from one application and read from the other.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thats exactly what I wanted to know, and I've marked it as the correct answer. Do you know of any examples of how to do this ?

Comment: BTW, for anyone who down voted this question, I'd love to know why, and obviously you weren't able to answer the question like Akbar did, so you shouldn't down vote something you have no clue about yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Akbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423338/akbar-ahmed) and [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5560606/john-m) that we can run multiple streams reading from different sources in parallel. 
I like add that if you want to share data between streams, you can use Spark SQL API. So you can register your RDD as a SQL table and access the same table in all the streams. This is possible since all the streams share the same SparkContext